# Laravel Passport is failing to validate my newly generated token

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, access-token, laravel-passport

Suddenly my application stopped working when trying to access endpoints protected by `auth:api` middleware in the Laravel 5.6.35 back-end using Passport 7.0.1.

The issue is that it is generating when I register and log-in.

```
return Response::json([
    'token' => $user->createToken('foobar')->accessToken,
    'user' => $user
], HTTPResponse::$HTTP_OK);
```

Insomnia rest will then show the following when accessing the routes belonging to the `auth:api` middleware.

> "message": "Unauthenticated."

It was working until an hour ago, and it stopped after I refreshed the database. I dropped and created a new one, registered a test user and attempted to access and endpoint passing the token as `Bearer` token and Accept header to `application/json`. I've done it like this many times, always running `php artisan passport:install --force` after each refresh.

[image]

I don't know how to solve it. I saw where it was failing in `TokenGuard.php` file, but what to do? Why has it suddenly stopped?

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the issue was because I was setting another field as the primary key of `users` table, and it was causing an error in the Passport's auto-generated tables.

Answer (score 0):

you must reinstall the passport after refreshed the database.Then only Token will generate

> php artisan passport:install

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Apache Server, Add this line to your httpd.conf file.

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```